# Code of filter that works with constants not symbols

Tags: recursion, filter, scheme, racket

```
(define-struct pizza (size toppings))


;; Constants for testing
(define (meat item)
  (symbol=? 'meat item))

(define (tomatoes item)
  (symbol=? 'tomatoes item))

(define (cheese item)
  (symbol=? 'cheese item))

(define (pepperoni item)
  (symbol=? 'pepperoni item))

(define (hot-peppers item)
  (symbol=? 'hot-peppers item))


(define (count-toppings order topping)
  (cond [(empty? order) 0]
        [else
  (local


    [(define (single-pizza-tops pizza top)
  (length (filter top (pizza-toppings pizza))))
    (define (list-of-nums lop tops)
  (list (single-pizza-tops (first lop) tops)
         (single-pizza-tops (first (rest lop)) tops)
               (single-pizza-tops (first (rest (rest lop))) tops)))]

  (foldr + 0 (list-of-nums order topping)))]))
```

Turns out my code works fine with the defined constants, but count-toppings wont work with a symbol for 'topping?

Does anyone know a way to modify my filter function so that if I input a symbol for toppings, this code will work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

`Map` and `filter` can be implemented in terms of `foldr` and `cons`. Since you aren't building a list you can disregard `filter` and `map`. In general though to map recursion to higher-order function you can look at type signatures. The more difficult way is to manually match your code to that of the functions.

Map takes a list, a function or arity one, and returns a list of the function mapped to each element of the list or `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` in Haskell notaion.

```
(define (map f L) ;niave implementation pared down for simplicity 
 (if (null? L)
     '()
     (cons (f (car L)) (map f (cdr L)))))
```

Filter takes a predicate of arity one, and a list, and returns a list that safisfies that predicate. or `(a -> bool) -> [a] -> [a]` in Haskell.

```
(define (filter pred L) ;dirro
 (cond ((null? L) '())
       ((pred (car L))
        (cons (car L)
              (filter pred (cdr L))))
       (else (filter pred (cdr L)))))
```

Foldr takes an a function that that has arity two, an accumulator value, and a list and returns the accumulator. or `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` in haskell.

```
(define (foldr kons knil L) ;ditto
  (if (null? L) 
      knil
      (kons (car L) (foldr kons knil (cdr L)))))
```

So the trick of it at first is assuaging the argument from your function to fit. In both your funcitons you have a cond clause `[(empty? topping-list) 0]`, which suggests knil should be `0`.

In `count-topping`'s else statement you call +, which at first glance suggests kons should be a +, however your list isn't numbers directly, meaning youll have to wrap in in a lambda statement, or create a helper function. `(lambda (x acc) (+ (single-pizza-toppings (pizza-toppings x) atop) acc))`

To put it together

```
(define (count-topping alop atop)
  (foldr (lambda (x acc) 
            (+ (single-pizza-toppings (pizza-toppings x) atop)       
               acc))  
         0
         alop))
```

Now the interesting one, `single-pizza-toppings` will look very similar. Execpt that the `lambda` statement will contain an `if` statment that returns 1 if x is a symbol equal to topping and 0 otherwise. Or you can do something even simpler.

```
(define (single-pizza-toppings topping-list topping)
  (foldr (lambda (x acc)
           (+ 1 acc))
         0
         (filter (lammba (x) (symbol=? x topping))
                 topping-list)))
```

That filter filter insures every `x` going to the `foldr` is a topping so you can just ignore it and add to the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that we have the first, we can define the second by

1. Count the occurrences of the topping in each pizza using the first function, by way of `map`
2. Compute the sum of the resulting list

That is,

```
(define (count-toppings pizzas topping)
  (sum (map (lambda (p) (single-pizza-toppings (pizza-toppings p) topping)) pizzas)))
```

For the first function, we can use `filter` to get a list of all occurrences of the given topping.
The number of occurrences is the length of the result:

```
(define (single-pizza-toppings toppings topping)
  (length (filter (lambda (t) (symbol=? t topping)) toppings)))
```

Both functions consist of a transformation of the input into the data we're interested in, `map` and `filter`, followed by a "reduction", `sum` and `length`.
This is a very common pattern.

And if you don't have `sum`:

```
(define (sum ts)
  (foldr (lambda (x acc) (+ x acc)) 0 ts))
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like your first step will be to put together a complete set of test cases. If you're using DrRacket, you might want to enable "Syntactic Test Suite Coverage" in the "Choose Language..." menu to make sure you have a good set of tests. That's the first step....

Comment: Test cases? Such as check-expects?

Comment: While that is good practice, it doesn't solve the issue at hand, which is how to reason in terms of higher-order funcitons.